# Stripe: can't remove the email field from paymentElement?

Tags: stripe-payments

Has anyone managed to hide the `email` field in a Stripe `paymentElement`? This code successfully hides `country`, but leaves `email` visible:

```
  const paymentElementOptions = {
     layout  : 'tabs',
     fields  : {
        billingDetails : {
           email   : 'never',
           address : {
              country : 'never'
           }
        }
     }
  };
  const paymentElement = elements.create('payment', paymentElementOptions);
```

The docs for `billingDetails` explicitly say that you can do this ([here](https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_payment_element#payment_element_create-customized_fields-fields-billingDetails)).

**EDIT**

I've just downloaded the Stripe demo code for 'Custom payment flow' and confirmed that it has exactly the same problem. Go [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart), select Web/HTML/Python, Custom payment flow, and the page shows the source code. The JS has 127 lines - replace lines 38-40 (the `paymentElementOptions` definition) with my code above, and the email field is still visible, but the Country field isn't. It only takes a few minutes to run up the demo from the download, if you've got Python 3.6+ installed, and the Python stripe package:

```
$ cd ~/Downloads/whatever 
$ unzip stripe-sample-code.zip 
$ export FLASK_APP=server.py 
$ python3 -m flask run --port=4242
```

Now browse to `http://localhost:4242/checkout.html`.

Comment: Is the payment element the only element you create? Can you share more of your front-end code?

Comment: @codename_duchess: link in edit above.

Comment: Since you've likely encountered a bug, I recommend writing in to Stripe's Support for them to investigate: https://support.stripe.com/

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Running into the same problem.

Comment: @MLyck: there's no fix. I can't find the message, but I'm pretty sure that tech support told me it's a feature.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and figured that their sample code has the "Link Authentication Element" which get's mounted into the page which is rendering this email address field. Look at the lines 31 and 32 on https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart checkout.js. If you remove those 2 lines the email address field goes away.